# EF code first - change generated column name for relationship

Tags: entity-framework-4

Using EF code first want to control the name of the genereted column WHEN REFERENCING SELF.  Tried `[ForeignKey]` and `[Column]` attributes. `[Column]` does not work and `[ForeignKey]` forces a relationship that seems to cause a problem.  I have used `[ForeignKey]` attribute to set the name of a column in another class/table connected to this one.

Have

```
public class Episodes
{
    public long ID {get; set;}
    // ... other properties

    public List<Episodes> Children { get; set; }
}
```

want a table (`ID`, ..., `ParentID`) - get a table (`ID`, ..., `Episode_ID`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the foreign key column exposed as property in your entity class you can define the column name only with Fluent API:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Episodes>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Children)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentID"));
```

I assume that the parent is optional (`ParentID` is a nullable column in the DB table) because, I guess, there should be some "root" in the tree, i.e. an episode that doesn't have a parent anymore, hence at least for this episode the `ParentID` column must be `NULL`.

Comment: answer looks good - but when i do this - get runtime error when EF creates the database "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: @SimonThompson: Can you show the code and the line of that code that exactly throws this exception?

Comment: there must of ben gremlins somewhere - its now working.  Thanks for the answer